# SQL, random number

Tags: sql, random, mariadb, floor

I am using MariaDB, version 11.1.2, client 15.2 for OSX10.17 (x86_64).

I can generate a random number using:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 1;
```

When run it will generate a random number between 1 and 50.  What I want to do is add a range of numbers or pattern that when it selects a random number it will ignore those in the mask, something like:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 50) + 1 NOT IN (5,11,21);
```

Comment: Generate a random number 1 to 47. Use a case expression to move 5 to 48, 11 to 49 and 21 to 50.

Comment: How much does this have to scale? Will it always be a relatively small list (<20) of exclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option for mariadb:

```
SELECT seq
FROM seq_1_to_50
WHERE seq NOT IN (5, 11, 21)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Brillant !, thank you

Comment: Slight variant on this....I would like to use the query to generate a number of random numbers, for example 6 random numbers between the same ranges but each chosen random number must be unique, can this also be done with a single query ?

Comment: @SPlatten just change the limit to 6? It already does everything you're asking.

Comment: @MatBailie, not quite, "must be unique" what I mean is I want N (6) random numbers between 1 and 50 no duplicates, [edit] actually I think it already does this.

Comment: @SPlatten This creates a sequence of unique numbers, then removes some of them, randomly orders the remaining numbers, then picks the first N of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a while loop like this

```
SET @x=FLOOR(RAND()*50)+1;

WHILE @x IN (5,11,21)
BEGIN
SET @x=FLOOR(RAND()*50)+1;
END
```

Comment: thank you, however I know I can do this in a stored function / procedure, I was really looking for an inline query.